# Error 110 while running make

Tags: java, android-source

I'm getting the following error:

> frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/mypackage/MyServiceListenerClass.java:283: error 110: Parameter of unavailable type android.os.storage.VolumeInfo in android.os.mypackage.MyServiceListenerClass.myMethod()

I have created a new package with some classes and those classes use `VolumeInfo` from the `storage` package.

I couldn't find any documentation on this error. What have I done wrong?

**UPDATE:**

- Found out that `Error 110 = UNAVAILABLE_SYMBOL`.
- Found this section in doclava/Stubs.java:

  ```
  for (ParameterInfo p :  m.parameters()) {
      TypeInfo t = p.type();
      if (!t.isPrimitive()) {
        hiddenClass = findHiddenClasses(t);
        if (null != hiddenClass) {
          if (hiddenClass.qualifiedName() == t.asClassInfo().qualifiedName()) {
            // Parameter type is hidden
            Errors.error(Errors.UNAVAILABLE_SYMBOL, m.position(),
                "Parameter of unavailable type " + t.fullName() + " in " + cl.qualifiedName()
                + "." + m.name() + "()");
          } else {
            // Parameter type contains a generic parameter
            Errors.error(Errors.HIDDEN_TYPE_PARAMETER, m.position(),
                "Parameter uses type parameter of unavailable type " + t.fullName() + " in "
                + cl.qualifiedName() + "." + m.name() + "()");
          }
        }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason for this error was the `@hide` attribute at the bottom of `VolumInfo`'s documentation part:

```
/**
 * Information about a storage volume that may be mounted. A volume may be a
 * partition on a physical {@link DiskInfo}, an emulated volume above some other
 * storage medium, or a standalone container like an ASEC or OBB.
 * <p>
 * Volumes may be mounted with various flags:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link #MOUNT_FLAG_PRIMARY} means the volume provides primary external
 * storage, historically found at {@code /sdcard}.
 * <li>{@link #MOUNT_FLAG_VISIBLE} means the volume is visible to third-party
 * apps for direct filesystem access. The system should send out relevant
 * storage broadcasts and index any media on visible volumes. Visible volumes
 * are considered a more stable part of the device, which is why we take the
 * time to index them. In particular, transient volumes like USB OTG devices
 * <em>should not</em> be marked as visible; their contents should be surfaced
 * to apps through the Storage Access Framework.
 * </ul>
 *
 * @hide
 */
```

Removing it solves the issue.